# How to generate a set of random points within a given (x,y) coordinates in an x-y plane?

Tags: python, random, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Suppose I want to take 4 clusters of points. Each cluster can be within a given set of x-y co ordinates. Each point within a cluster is a random generated point.

These clusters will be acting as input for my K-Means clustering problem. 
How do I do it using Python?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Is the area bounded by your points regular in nature?

Comment: x = random(), y = random(), make a for loop and store them in a list.

Comment: Could you give us maybe a rough sketch of what you think this should look like?

Comment: What sort of probability distribution do you want for the points? If you are doing machine learning then the term "random" is underdetermined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might give you some ideas:

```
from random import random
import math

def rand_cluster(n,c,r):
    """returns n random points in disk of radius r centered at c"""
    x,y = c
    points = []
    for i in range(n):
        theta = 2*math.pi*random()
        s = r*random()
        points.append((x+s*math.cos(theta), y+s*math.sin(theta)))
    return points
```

This function can be used in various ways, for example:

```
def rand_clusters(k,n,r, a,b,c,d):
    """return k clusters of n points each in random disks of radius r
where the centers of the disk are chosen randomly in [a,b]x[c,d]"""
    clusters = []
    for _ in range(k):
        x = a + (b-a)*random()
        y = c + (d-c)*random()
        clusters.extend(rand_cluster(n,(x,y),r))
    return clusters
```

A typical all would look like

```
clusters = rand_clusters(4,50,0.3,0,1,0,1)
```

This generates 4 clusters of size 50 of radius `0.3` with centers chosen at random in the unit square. Points from a typical run:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate data using

```
min + (max - min) * random()
```

Then they will be between min and max.

Do this for x and y, and for every cluster.